# Created key from wrong file, how could I modify it / work around the issue?

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I created a key from the wrong file by mistake:

```
gcloud kms encrypt --plaintext-file=keys/staging-access-chris \
       --ciphertext-file=id_rsa.enc \
       --location=global --keyring="$keyRing" --key=bitbucket
```

How can I update / edit this entry? Do I need to change the file name and all references to it or is there a solution that requires less work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'encrypt' function takes a plaintext (raw data) as input and produces a ciphertext (encrypted data) as output.  It does not create a key.

If you meant to encrypt a different file, the fix is to simply delete the ciphertext you don't want, correct the command, and repeat.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I didn't think this through end to end! Helpful indeed, thank you!